# Slack API Postmessage

Tags: ruby, api, httparty, slack

I'm looking at the Slack API for use in teaching API Consumption in Ruby.  Does the Slack API require all the parameters as part of the query string or can it take post-Params as well.

Messages like this work:

```
def self.sendmsg(channel, msg)
    url = BASE_URL + "chat.postMessage?" + "token=#{TOKEN}" + "&text=#{msg}&channel=#{channel}"
    data = HTTParty.post(url)
end
```

However this does not:

```
  def self.sendmsg(channel, msg)
    url = BASE_URL + "chat.postMessage?" + "token=#{TOKEN}"
    data = HTTParty.post(url,
               body: {
                  "text" => "#{msg}",
                  "channel" => "#{channel}"
             }.to_json,
             :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' } )
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cleanest answer is just this:

```
url = 'https://someslackwebhookurl/adfdsf/sdfsfsd'
msg = 'We are fumanchu'
HTTParty.post(url, body: {"text":"#{msg}"}.to_json)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to answer the question with:

```
    data = HTTParty.post(url,
           body:  {
              "text" => "#{msg}",
              "channel" => "#{channel}",
              "username" => bot_name,
              "icon_url" => icon_url,
              "as_user" => "false"
            },
         :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })
```

It won't work with JSON content oddly enough.